# jQuery off click with same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button, and what I have is when you click on it, and new element "drops" in. So what I want to do is when you press it *again* it goes back. As essentially fades out. Here's what I have so far \

```
$(".icon-search").click(function(){
    $(".search").css('height', '100px')
});
```

When you click on the icon, the black shape goes to `100px`. And what I want to do, is get rid of it, by clicking on it again. I've seen other stuff online, but none seemed to work.

Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/PHX3A/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHX3A/2/)

`.toggleClass()` will do the trick for you.

`.toggleClass()` :

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of
>   matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
>   value of the switch argument.

**JavaScript** :

```
$(".icon-search").click(function(){
    $(".search").toggleClass("doHeight");
});
```

**CSS** :

```
.doHeight{
 height:100px;   
}
```

for further information in using `.toggleClass()` click [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

**2nd Option** :

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHX3A/4/)

using `.toggle()` reference : [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

JS :

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $( ".search" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: How would I apply a transition? I tried `transition: 1s` in `.doHeight`, but it didn't work. I want the black to fade in.

Comment: I really don't see what you did. How did you apply it?

Comment: it's on your `jquery.js` it does the magic for you. not me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function to set the `CSS`. In this example, I added `CSS` to the `toggle` class

**Try this:**

**JQuery:**

```
$(".icon-search").click(function(){
    $(".search").toggleClass('toggle')
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.toggle{
    height:100px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PHX3A/1/)**